# Sort element by numerical value of data attribute WITHOUT Jquery

Tags: javascript, sorting

How would I go about converting this code to regular javascript??

```
    function sortList(listName,dataName){
    var $people = $(listName);

    $peopleli = $people.children('.leader-mobile');
    $peopleli.sort(function(a,b){
        console.log(b);
        var an = a.getAttribute(dataName),
        bn = b.getAttribute(dataName);
        if(an < bn) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(an > bn) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    $peopleli.detach().appendTo($people);
}
```

Its used like

```
 sortList($('#myList'),'data-close');
```

Im trying to sort a list based on a data attribute,  and I CANT use jQuery.

Im limited from using jquery by the jqMobi framework which only has minimal jquery compatibility.

I figured that before I find a way to make jqMobi and Jquery to play together.
I figured Id learn how to actually do it in pure javascript first

Comment: well the sort() and detach() methods aren't available to use in jqMobi  I can select the elements data values and put/sort them in an array, and sort that easily.  But I was hoping to sort by the elements themselves not a proxy array

Comment: yes Im sure... it doesn't work.  It breaks in jqmobi, and works on my regular site.  Same exact function, and html, nothing different.  Aside from the fact that on the mobile, Im not loading jquery

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it like this...by just sorting the objects first then applying that sorted object to the DOM, as opposed to getting the elements from the DOM and sorting them after placement.  Worked out much better and faster

```
   var sort_by = function(field, reverse, primer){
       var key = primer ? 
           function(x) {return primer(x[field])} : 
           function(x) {return x[field]};

       reverse = [-1, 1][+!!reverse];

       return function (a, b) {
           return a = key(a), b = key(b), reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
         } 
    }

    salesSort.sort(sort_by('sales',false,parseInt));
    unitSort.sort(sort_by('units',false,parseInt));
    closeSort.sort(sort_by('close',false,parseInt));
```